# Codename One - Customizing TextField

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm trying to customize the standard TextField appearance, in order to add padding, to change borders and to change padding for both text and text hint.

In Codename One Designer, I created my CustomTextField style, starting from the existing TextField: I correctly added padding and changed borders, but the padding I set does not affect the text hint. 
As you can see in the following picture, the cursor correctly started from the padding, but the hint does not consider it.

[image]

Moreover, when I start to insert text, it does not consider the padding.
[image]

In CustomTextField style, I set padding for unselected, selected and pressed states.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

You need to style `TextHint` too in order for this to apply there. It's a separate style since it has a different font as a result the padding etc. is also different.

Comment: And if I want to use both the "standard" TextHint and the custom TextHint, how can I assign the custom one to the custom text field? Is there a setHintStyle method for TextField class?

Comment: Use `text.getHintLabel().setUIID("CustomHint");`

Comment: Good, I solved the hint issue. However, I can't solve the other problem: when I start to insert text inside the text field, the padding I set disappeared (you can see the second picture in my question).

Comment: Is this on the simulator only or on the device too? You can use the `nativeHintBool=false` theme constant to hide the native hint which might not respect the padding settings.

Comment: The issue is on both the simulator and the device. Where do I have to set the nativeHintBool constant? But, are you sure it could be the solution? I'm noticing this problem on text I type.

Comment: This is a "theme constant" see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html#_theme_constants

Comment: I added the nativeHintBool constant and set it to false, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you test this on an Android device? It should be resolved there, regarding other platforms we might need to file an issue.

Comment: I didn't test on Android device. I only tested it on iOS device, as I'm developing an app for iOS.

Comment: I suggest filing an issue, if you have access to an Android device it would be great if you can see whether this solution is satisfactory there